# If an onfocus event handler is added with attachEvent, how can I access it?

Tags: javascript, events, vba, handler

#### Background:

I'm writing a script (in VBA, if that matters) to input data into a web-based system. Some of the system's validation is only run when a field is focused, so I've been calling `.Focus` on the fields in VBA to force it to run. But that steals the systemwide focus; rather annoying if I am doing anything else while the job is running.

I want the validation to be triggered without stealing the focus. So I am trying to directly call whatever event handler is registered to the input field.

#### Problem:

All event handlers in the web app are added with `element.attachEvent()`, which means the `onfocus` and `onblur` properties (which I believe are the ones I want) are not set.
**Is there any way to retrieve the handlers without resorting to even more evil hacks?**

Alternatively, is there a better way to do this without having to find the event handlers? I'm pretty new to JavaScript, so I could easily be missing something.

---

**Edit:** Is there any other reason the focus might be stolen by the VBA code? I cannot find any other references to `.Focus` or even AutoIt's `WinActivate`, but even with the suggestions here, the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The whole VBA part aside, you appear to have a reference to an `element`, so you can try calling `element.focus()` or `element.blur()` to trigger the focus and blur events respectively.

Comment: But `.focus` seems to grab the systemwide focus anyway, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I'm just saying that I tried it and it did. Unless I was doing something else that caused it, but I didn't see any other calls to the uppercase `Focus`.

Comment: @mmyers: hmm interesting. Perhaps I'm not familiar enough with the VBA part of this question. If I call `setTimeout(function(){ $('[name=q]')[0].focus() }, 2000)` on this page, then switch to a different application (eg Powerpoint) and wait 2 seconds, the page does *not* steal focus again.

Comment: I'm not familiar with VBA either, but I searched again and I still can't find anything that would steal focus. I hope this question isn't completely unrelated to the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [post](http://jehiah.cz/archive/firing-javascript-events-properly).

This function should fire the event for you:

```
function fireEvent(element,event){
    if (document.createEventObject){
        // dispatch for IE
        var evt = document.createEventObject();
        return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
    }
    else{
        // dispatch for firefox + others
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
        return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

Do you have access to the application you are interacting with (to be able to add this function)?

Comment: No, but I may be able to do that from VBA. I'll give it a shot now. Thanks!

Comment: Also, this is an internal application which is guaranteed to use IE, so that makes it easier.